# Decision of Static methods vs instance methods in java?

Tags: java

As per my understanding we should go for instance methods only when they are dealing with state of object i.e instance variable . If method does deal with state of object they should always be declared as class methods i.e static. But still in most of the projects
i ihave seen the methods which never not operates on instance variables they are also declared as instance methods(basically what these methods are doing they are using some of the method parametrs and doing some processing on that paremets and calling some other classes).Thats it.
**Should not these methods should be declared as class method i.e static ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's likely the answer is yes: if you have an instance method that *doesn't actually take advantage of the instance state*, then it should probably be `static`, and possibly moved to a helper class depending on what it does.

Note that even if you don't access instance variables, accessing instance methods will also disqualify a method from becoming `static`. Also, if this method is an instance method in order to future-proof it (in anticipation of using the instance state later,) then changing it wouldn't be advisable either.

Also important is that public non-static methods could be inherited and overriden by a subclass, so making them `static` could actually break the code in possibly unexpected ways.

Comment: Thanks dlev. Could you little bit explain your statement i.e "Note that even if you don't access instance variables, accessing instance methods will also disqualify a method from becoming static"

Comment: What I mean is that if you have a method that doesn't access the instnace state directly, it still can't be `static` if it *does* call another instance method.

Comment: how come  calling  another instance method disqualify a method from becoming static? Sorry for troubling you . Please bear me.

Comment: Because instance methods require an  instance.

Comment: +1 If the methods are `private static`, this answer is probably correct. However, when it comes to `public` methods, it becomes an API question. If the method might ever become dependent on an instance field, or if you want to make it available as part of an interface, you suddenly have to go through your entire code-base to de-staticize all your method calls.

Comment: @Mohit think about it this way: an instance method needs an instance, which a static method doesn't have(nor require) so it can't call an instance method (an it's actually a warning to call a static method as an instance method)

Comment: @Stripling good point; I should have elaborated on my "future-proofing" remark.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a [possibly incomplete] list when you must use instance methods over static ones:

- you access instance variables / methods from within the method
- the method is an abstract method that you implement
- the method is an interface method that you implement
- you have doubts about the method staying static in the long-term
- you declare it `synchronized` and don't want to lock on the class, rather on the instance
- you get warnings when accessing static methods in a non-static way and you really care about them (sometimes you just can't avoid calling in a non-static way, so your only choice is making them methods non-static)

You could probably go static in all other cases.

Answer (score 5):

Static methods have the disadvantage that they tightly couple callers to the implementation. Instance methods can be overridden or can be one of multiple implementations of an interface method.

In other words, instance methods can promote loose coupling, testability, and reuse.

Comment: I agree, I think all you points are valid reasons and should be promoted more.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect everyone to follow a path all the time whether it is best practice or not. First, we are all humans. We can choose a way over something different sometimes and that shouldn't be fully correct all the time. Even Frameworks and Libraries and Languages are created by humans so an error shouldn't surprise you or bedazzle you.

For everything else, I concur dlev.

Comment: That's a good point, people do make mistakes. It's usually not a big deal to have an instance method that could be `static`, and it in fact happens all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we're designing a new language and we want Sqrt to be an instance method. So we look at the double class and begin designing. It obviously has no inputs (other than the instance) and returns a double. We write and test the code. Perfection.

But taking the square root of an integer is valid, too, and we don't want to force everyone to convert to a double just to take a square root. So we move to int and start designing. What does it return? We could return an int and make it work only for perfect squares, or round the result to the nearest int (ignoring the debate about the proper rounding method for now). But what if someone wants a non-integer result? Should we have two methods - one that returns an int and one that returns a double (which is not possible in some languages without changing the name). So we decide that it should return a double. Now we implement. But the implementation is identical to the one we used for double. Do we copy-and-paste? Do we cast the instance to a double and call that instance method? Why not put the logic in a library method that can be accessed from both classes. We'll call the library Math and the function Math.Sqrt.